# Leaflet - UTFGrid - add popup

Tags: popup, leaflet

I know it's a beginner question and probably very easy but I can't get it to work. I have a map with 2 utfgrids which show an information about bicycle and hiking routes. It is based on this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/milkbread/6449317

It works fine but I would like to change it this way. When hoovering the existing infobox should show up but when clicking on the route the popup should show up in the place where I clicked (with the same information that shows up in the infobox). 
I tried different ways to apply it but I always get an error. Here's a link to my working webiste and a part of the code responsible for the infobox window.

http://wojtas82.zrujnowane.pl/utf2.html#15/54.5027/18.4886/osm-rowerowe-piesze

And the code:

```
    utfGrid2.on('mouseover', function(e){ info.update(e);}).on('mouseout', function(e){ info.update();})

    utfGrid1.on('mouseover', function(e){ info.update(e);}).on('mouseout', function(e){ info.update();})

    var info = L.control();
    info.options.position = 'bottomleft';
    info.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };


    info.update = function (props) {
        this._div.innerHTML = (props ?
        '<img src="img/' + props.data.route +'_'+ props.data.osmc_color +'_'+ props.data.osmc_background +'_'+ props.data.osmc_foreground + '.png" ><br /> ' + "<b>" + props.data.name + "</b><br />" + 'Długość: ' + (props.data.distance ? props.data.distance : '') + ' km'  + "<br />" + 'Opis szlaku: ' + (props.data.description ? props.data.description : '')   : '');
    };
```

I will be very greatful for help.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using 
`L.popup` for your popup? Something like

```
utfGrid1.on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.data) {
        L.popup()
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent(e ? '<img src="img/' + e.data.route + '_' + e.data.osmc_color + '_' + e.data.osmc_background + '_' + e.data.osmc_foreground + '.png" ><br /> ' + "<b>" + e.data.name + "</b><br />" + 'Długość: ' + (e.data.distance ? e.data.distance : '') + ' km' + "<br />" + 'Opis szlaku: ' + (e.data.description ? e.data.description : '')).openOn(map);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, First of all thank you very much for your anwser. I added this code and popup shows up. The problem is that it shows up even if I click outside the route. The other problem is that if I change the 'content' to props.data.name nothing shows up. Here's a refreshed link : http://wojtas82.zrujnowane.pl/utf3.html#14/54.5602/18.3417/osm-rowerowe-piesze

Comment: You need to replace your `prop` by `e` here. I don't really know what `utfGrid`s are, so I assumed they are your path? When your `mouseover`/`mouseout`-events work with the `onclick` as you described, the popup should work similar and only apply on clicks on the `utfGrid1`/`utfGrid2` - whatever they may be. EDIT: Read about it. Changed my function to check if data is applied to the onclick event.

Comment: This just perfect. Working great! Thanks a lot!